# Unable to add to source control as load state is update cancelled

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

we are using snapshot view (UCM).

While we tried to add source control a folder it fails with following error.

```
Rational ClearCase Explorer
---------------------------

 Error adding 'D:\cc_view\IS-Dev1\Impl\Install\ViewDeployment' to source control.

Checkout is currently disabled for element "D:\cc_view\IS-Dev1\Impl\Install".  An update appears to have been aborted or errors were  encountered during an update.  An update must be performed  on the element to enable a checkout. Checkout is currently disabled for element "D:\cc_view\IS-Dev1\Impl\Install".  Its config spec rule information is currently unavailable  due to either an aborted update or an update in progress.
```

We have updated the view once again and stop and start the clearcase related services.

But still no improvement. When we look at properties of view-> advanced tab . it show Load state: Update cancelled.

I think this state may play a role. How to solve this and allow it to add to source code control?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to launch the update at the root directory of the snapshot view (above the vobs), because UCM might complain because of the configuration change.
If the Stream has been rebased, then an update would ask for you to accept the new configuration and launch a full update, but only if done from the root directory of the view.

Check also the logs of those updates (file `*.updt` in the root folder of the view), any error in it would mean a "Update cancelled" for the view.

A way to get a full update in your case would be (still at the root folder, as in [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC48021) -- for CCRC but also valid for a full ClearCase installation):

```
 cleartool setcs -current
```

Comment: So, short answer: `cd /root/snaphotView ; cleartool setcs -current`. Then try your "add to source control".

Answer (score 0):

Previous update or checkout is uncompleted. You have to update your snapshot view. You can run

```
cleartool setcs -current
```

OR

```
ClearCase Explorer->(on left panel--snapshot_name) right click-> Update View->Yes
```

that operation take a long time. That operation completed after this problem fixed.

Warning: Dont stop updating processing. You shouldn't start this operation while starting. Because you cant do progress  while clear case updating to view.